# Problema al pasar variables entre pantallas

Tags: flutter, variables, rutas, ventana

*Hola, tengo un problema al querer pasar una variable de una pantalla a otra, lo que pasa es que al terminar el codigo me sigue apareciendo un error en el main, especificamente en una de las rutas, y en la pantalla de donde sale la variable que son pes y alt.tambien en la pantalla en la que la variable debe llegar ya tiene el codigo correspondiente
el error en el main aparece en la ruta de la pantalla donde la variable va a llegar, no se como se podria solucionar esto.*

```
 
 class primera_4 extends StatelessWidget {
    primera_4({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
 
   final peso= TextEditingController();
   final altura= TextEditingController();
 
   var pes= '' ;
   var alt= '';
 
 
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: SizedBox(
         width: double.infinity,
         height: double.infinity,
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Container(
               width: double.infinity,
               height: 170,
               decoration: BoxDecoration(
                   gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                     Color.fromRGBO(181, 253, 125, 1),
                     Color.fromRGBO(124, 250, 215, 1)
                   ]),
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                   boxShadow: [
                     BoxShadow(
                       color: Colors.black12,
                       blurRadius: 15,
                       offset: Offset(0, 5),
                     ),
                   ]),
               child: Column(
                 children: [
                   SizedBox(
                     height: 60,
                   ),
                   Text('¡CADA 15 DIAS!',style: TextStyle(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         fontFamily: 'Seis',
                         fontSize: 40,
                       ),),
                 ],
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 10,
             ),
             SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Column(
                 children: [
                   SizedBox(
                     height: 10,
                   ),
                   Container(
                     padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                     margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                     width: double.infinity,
                     height: 490,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         color: Colors.white,
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                         boxShadow: [
                           BoxShadow(
                             color: Color.fromARGB(31, 240, 9, 221),
                             blurRadius: 50,
                             offset: Offset(4, 8),
                           ),
                         ]),
                     child: Column(
                       children: [
                         SizedBox(
                           height: 10,
                         ),
                         Text('PESO Y ALTURA',
                           style: TextStyle(
                                           color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                                            fontFamily: 'Seis',
                               fontSize: 30,
                                         ),),
                         SizedBox(
                           height: 30,
                         ),
                         Container(
                           child: Form(
                             autovalidateMode:
                                 AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                             child: Column(
                               children: [
                                 Text('¿CUAL ES TU PESO HOY?',style: TextStyle(
                                           color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                                            fontFamily: 'Seis',
                               fontSize: 15,
                                         ),),
                                 SizedBox(
                                   height: 10,
                                 ),
                                 TextField(
                                   controller: peso,
                                     autocorrect: false,
                                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                                       enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                           borderSide: BorderSide(
                                               color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                   124, 250, 215, 1))),
                                       focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                         borderSide: BorderSide(
                                             color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                 124, 250, 215, 1),
                                             width: 2),
                                       ),
                                       hintText: '75',
                                       labelText: 'Peso',
                                       prefixIcon: Icon(
                                         Icons.monitor_weight_rounded,
                                       ),
                                     )),
                                 SizedBox(
                                   height: 20,
                                 ),
                                 MaterialButton(
                                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                   disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                   color: Color.fromRGBO(124, 250, 215, 1),
                                   onPressed: () {
                                     pes= peso.text;
 
                                     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute <Null> (
                                       builder: (BuildContext){
                                         return new primera(**pes**);
                                       }
                                       ));
                                     peso.text='';
                                   },
                                   child: Container(
                                     padding:
                                         EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                             horizontal: 50, vertical: 15),
                                     child: Text(
                                       'AGREGAR',
                                       style: TextStyle(
                                           color: Colors.white,
                                            fontFamily: 'Seis',
                               fontSize: 15,
                                         ),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                                 SizedBox(
                                   height: 30,
                                 ),
                                 Text('¿CUAL ES TU ALTURA HOY?',style: TextStyle(
                                           color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                                            fontFamily: 'Seis',
                               fontSize: 15,
                                         ),),
 
                                  SizedBox(
                                   height: 10,
 
                                 ),
                                 TextField(
                                   controller: altura,
                                     autocorrect: false,
                                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                                       enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                           borderSide: BorderSide(
                                               color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                   124, 250, 215, 1))),
                                       focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                         borderSide: BorderSide(
                                             color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                                 124, 250, 215, 1),
                                             width: 2),
                                       ),
                                       hintText: '1.75',
                                       labelText:
                                           'Altura',
                                       prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                                     )),
                                 SizedBox(
                                   height: 20,
                                 ),
                                 MaterialButton(
                                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                                   disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                   color: Color.fromRGBO(124, 250, 215, 1),
                                   onPressed: () {
                                     alt=altura.text;
 
                                     Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute <Null> (
                                       builder: (BuildContext context){
                                         return new primera(**alt**);
                                       }
                                       ));
 
                                     altura.text='';
                                   },
                                   child: Container(
                                     padding: //espacio adentro del boton, cuadro, lo que sea
                                         EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                             horizontal: 50, vertical: 15),
                                     child: Text(
                                       'AGREGAR',
                                       style: TextStyle(
                                           color: Colors.white,
                                            fontFamily: 'Seis',
                               fontSize: 15,
                                         ),
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),

                           ],
                         ),
                       ),
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ),
               SizedBox(
                 height: 20,
               ),
               MaterialButton(
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                 disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                 color: Color.fromRGBO(181, 253, 125, 1),
                 onPressed: () {
                   Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'primera');
                 },
                 child: Container(
                   padding: //espacio adentro del boton, cuadro, lo que sea
                       EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 15),
                   child: Text(
                     'FINALIZAR',
                     style: TextStyle(
                                       color: Colors.white,
                                        fontFamily: 'Seis',
                           fontSize: 15,
                                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               )
             ],
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

y la pagina del main seria esta:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Material App',
      routes: {
        'Login': (_) => loginscreen(),
        'Login.1':(_)=> loginscreen1(),
        'cero': (_)=> cero(),
        'primera': (_)=> primera(),
        'primera_1': (_)=> primera_1(),
        'primera_4': (_)=> primera_4(),
        'segunda': (_)=> segunda(),
        'segunda_1': (_)=> segunda_1(),
        'segunda_1_1': (_)=> segunda_1_1(),
        'segunda_1_2': (_)=> segunda_1_2(),
        'segunda_1_3': (_)=> segunda_1_3(),
        'segunda_2': (_)=> segunda_2(),
        'segunda_4':(_)=> segunda_4(),
        'segunda_5':(_)=> segunda_5(),
        'tercera': (_)=> tercera(),
        'tercera_1': (_)=> tercera_1(),
        'cero_1': (_)=> cero_1(),
      },
      initialRoute: 'Login',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te juro que he leído el texto 3 veces y no he entendido ni papa. Seguramente, el fallo sea mío, pero quizás venga bien pegarle un repaso al texto que has escrito, por si crees que puedas mejorar o aclarar algún punto.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8eq8T6XDFs , de aca fue donde yo saque las bases para pasar parametros o variables entre pantallas, pero lo que sucede es que en el main principal me aparece un error, el error es especificamente aca:  'primera': (_)=> primera()

Comment: y esto es lo que me aparece en consola al querer ejecutar el codigo: